# How to include only updated item on array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wanted to create an array that includes only my last users so I did the following :

```
// This array should include only the last users 
let recived_msg_users = [];

//This function is been called after user insert to the DB
export function chat_afterInsert(item, context) {
  let user_date = []

  // Users ID
  item.userIdb;
  // Insertion date
  item._createdDate;

  user_date.push(item.userIdb)
  user_date.push(item._createdDate)
  recived_msg_users.push(user_date)
  console.log("new msg added", recived_msg_users)
  removeOldUsers(recived_msg_users)
  console.log("after remove old msg", recived_msg_users)
}

export function removeOldUsers(recived_msg_users) {
  var now = new Date();
  var nowTimeStamp = now.getTime();

  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < recived_msg_users.length; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(recived_msg_users[recived_msg_users.length - i - 1][1] - nowTimeStamp) < 60000) {
      recived_msg_users[recived_msg_users.length - i - 1][1].fruit
    } else {
      return
    }
  }
}
```

After running this code I got the only one array, for example `[['1111', '2020-01-01:20:30:31']]`
but because every 100 MS a new user insert to my DB I expected to see many arrays items, like this

```
[['1111', '2020-01-01:20:30:34'],['1111', '2020-01-01:20:30:41'],['1111', '2020-01-01:20:30:71'],['1111', '2020-01-01:20:30:91'], ... ]
```

I expected array to include items with less than 60 sec from creation, what is wrong?

Comment: Small side note; declaring `let i` *outside* of the `for()` kinda defeats the purpose of using a let there.

Comment: Statements like `item.userIdb;` don't do anything.

Comment: `recived_msg_users[recived_msg_users.length - i - 1][1].fruit` <= this doesn't do anything

Comment: `recived_msg_users.push(user_date)` <= you are only ever pushing to the array.  I don't see where you are ever removing from it.

Comment: Nothing in your code is an object with a `fruit` property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `filter()` method.

```
recived_msg_users = recived_msg_users.filter(([user, date]) => Math.abs(data - nowTimeStamp) < 60000);
```

Note that this doesn't modify the array in place, it returns a new array. So your function will need to return the array, and you'll need to do:

```
recived_msg_users = removeOldUser(recived_msg_users);
```

Comment: I think I found the reason, there is a difference between now time and server time, I print it on the console, but the diff is looking good
now time 1587149610695
received time 2020-04-17T18:53:30.799Z 
time diff 104
after I changed the function to be like your, the same issue happened

Comment: I found something, even if I NOT use remove function the items did not insert into the array so maybe it's sever issue or push issue.

Comment: If they didn't insert into the array, you obviously can't remove them. That's a completely different problem.

Comment: No , for some reason there is only one item in the array